# Magento: by php excel reader, read an excel file

Tags: excel, magento

I am new in magento and using 1.7.2. Could you please let me know how to integrate PHP excel Reader in magento so that system can read an excel file?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is very vague as to why you want to read an excel file. You can import/export csv files directly in Magento, or use Magmi to import csv files containing products.

Answer (score 0):

Magento generally has the functionality for reading the files in **.CSV** format.
If you need to integrate excel reader then you can do it by creating you own custom module.But **.CSV** is also a good option to go with...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read csv file in magento you can do like this.

```
if(isset($_FILES['file_uplod']['name']) && ($_FILES['file_uplod']['name'] != ''))
     {

        $filename = $_FILES['file_uplod']['name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

      $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('file_uplod');
      $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('text/csv',
    'csv','excel','vnd.ms-excel',
    'application/csv',
    'text/comma-separated-values',
    'application/excel',
    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'application/vnd.msexcel',
    'text/anytext',
    'application/octet-stream',
    'application/txt')); 
       $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true); //for creating the directory if not exists
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false); //if true, uploaded file's name will be changed, if file with the same name already exists directory.
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);       
      $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ;    

      $path = $path ."csv-folder";

      $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['file_uplod']['name']);

      $file = $path."/".$_FILES['file_uplod']['name'];
      $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['file_uplod']['name']);

      $file = $path."/".$_FILES['file_uplod']['name'];
      $csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
      $data = $csv->getData($file);
    //first line are the headers
    $headers = $data[0];
    $allProductData = array();
    for($i=1; $i<count($data); $i++){
      $productData = array();
      foreach ($headers as $index=>$attributeCode) {
          $productData[$attributeCode] = $data[$i][$index];
      }
      $allProductData[] = $productData;
  }
```

print the  `$allProductData` array here to get all the data inside the csv.Hope this help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the excel file in magento. you need open source project "[PHP-ExcelReader class](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/.)"

sample code as follows

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS;

    $path_to_XML = $path . "csv-folder" . DS . "magento.xls";
    $include_path = dirname(__FILE__);
    $path_to_PHP_ExcelReader = $include_path . "/Excel/reader.php";

    require_once $path_to_PHP_ExcelReader;

    // ExcelFile($filename, $encoding);
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

    // Set output Encoding.
    $data->setOutputEncoding('utf-8');
    /* if you want you can change 'iconv' to mb_convert_encoding: */

    $data->setUTFEncoder('mb');

    /*
     * By default rows & cols indeces start with 1
     * For change initial index use:
     */
    $index = 0;

    $data->setRowColOffset($index);
    /* setDefaultFormat - set format for columns with unknown formatting */

    $data->setDefaultFormat('%.2f');

    /* setColumnFormat - set format for column (apply only to number fields) */
    $data->setColumnFormat(4, '%.3f');
    /* Do the actual reading of file */

    $data->read($path_to_XML);
    echo "<pre>";


    print_r($data);
    exit;
```

All you need to do is extract [this zip](http://inchoo.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/read_xls.zip) to same directory that contains your class that need XLS support